# Can cloud functions be triggered by the state change of a google sheets document?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-sheets-api

I have a node script that formats a google sheets document using the google drive api and google-spreadsheet npm package. It retrieves data from one sheet in the document and then formats it into a nice dashboard.

However the data it retrieves from that particular sheet is dynamic and will change over time and it would be quite inconvenient to my other partners if I have to be at my pc to run the script for them whenever they populate more data into the sheet.

Considering cloud functions are triggered by a HTTP request, I assume I'd some how have to run an anonymous app that captures the state of a google sheet, then calls the HTTP. However I'm not sure what kind of app I'd have to create that could track a google sheets in real time?

Is this possible and if so what would be the correct method to go about such a task?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'd like to find a way to run a Firebase Cloud function that is
> triggered by the state change of a google sheets document.

You could use an [AppScript simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) like `onEdit()` to call an HTTP Cloud Function by using the [UrlFetchApp Class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app).

More details on HTTP Cloud Functions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events).

---

Note that you could use the same approach to directly read/write from/to Firestore by calling the [Firestore REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest).

Comment: This is very insightful. So if I'm understanding you correctly, AppScript can communicate in real time between a google sheets document? Then of course if that is the case I can just call the HTTP on edit of the document?

Comment: Yes, as explained in the UrlFetchApp Class doc: "This service allows scripts to communicate with other applications or access other resources on the web **by fetching URLs**" So to communicate "in real time" you need to couple a call to an HTTP Cloud Function URL with a trigger, e.g. `onEdit()`.